# The run destination iPhone 5.0 Simulator is not valid for running the scheme 'MyApp'

Tags: ios5

When I am trying to run the app. I am getting a error like this!!

> The run destination iPhone 5.0 Simulator is not valid for running the scheme 'MyApp'
>
> The scheme 'MyApp' contains no buildables that can be built for the SDKs supported by the run destination iPhone 5.0 Simulator. Make sure your targets all specify SDKs that are supported by this version of Xcode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what are your options set to for in the proejct options? you need to tell it is uses ios5 as the deployment target or base sdk/etc...